# Minimum amount of required chits to award player points

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, recreational-mathematics, discrete-optimization, card-games

There is a board game for up to four players that has 7 rounds and at the end of each round the game awards the first player 3 points, the second 2, the third 1 and the fourth 0 points.

The points are awarded to each player through chits. There are 7 3-point chits, 7 2-point chits and 7 1-point chits for a total of 21 chits.

What would be the minimum amount of chits required, if the chits could represent any integer value and the players could exchange chits back and forth?  For example, if a player had 3 points and got awarded 3 more, they could exchange their 3-point chits with:

a. a 6-point chit or
b. a 5-point chit and a 1-point chit or
c. a 4-point chit and a 2-point chit or
d. any other combination of chits

I understand that this will obviously NOT be the most convenient way to award points to the users, since the players will have to keep hunting for the appropriate chit combination to keep their score, but the question came up during game design and thought of asking here...

Thanks!

Comment: For the record, a simpler, more effective system, would 
lots of 1 chits and 5 chits or maybe 
lots of 1 chits, 3 chits, 5 chits and maybe a few 10 chits pieces.

Comment: Do it like with money, with 1,2,5,10 you have all possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first step is to enumerate the multisets of possible scores.  For example, at the end of round 1, the scores are $\{3,2,1,0\}$, and at the end of round 2 they can be any of the following $16$ multisets:

```
3 3 3 3 
4 3 3 2 
4 4 2 2 
4 4 3 1 
4 4 4 0 
5 3 2 2 
5 3 3 1 
5 4 2 1 
5 4 3 0 
5 5 1 1 
5 5 2 0 
6 2 2 2 
6 3 2 1 
6 3 3 0 
6 4 1 1 
6 4 2 0
```

It turns out that there are $792$ such multisets across the $7$ rounds.

Now you can use integer linear programming to find a smallest multiset of chits that can cover each multiset.  Let nonnegative integer decision variable $x_i$ be the number of chits of amount $i$.  Let nonnegative integer decision variable $y_{ijm}$ be the number of chits of amount $i$ used to represent score $j$ in multiset $m$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^{21} x_i$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_i i\ y_{ijm} &= j &&\text{for all $m$ and $j\in m$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_{j\in m} y_{ijm} &\le x_i &&\text{for all $m$ and $i$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} represents each $j$.
Constraint \eqref{2} uses only the available chits.

In your example solution, $x_1=x_2=x_3=7$, yielding objective value $21$.

A better solution is $x_1=x_2=2, x_3=12$, with objective value $16$.

An optimal solution turns out to be $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_5=x_7=2, x_6=1$, with objective value $11$.

An alternative optimal solution is $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_6=2, x_4=x_5=x_9=1$, with objective value $11$.

---

Additional results in response to the comments:

Restricting to $i\in\{1,3,5,10\}$ yields optimal solution $x_1=6,x_3=5,x_5=3,x_{10}=1$, with objective value $15$.

Restricting to $i\in\{1,2,5,10\}$ yields optimal solution $x_1=4,x_2=6,x_5=4,x_{10}=1$, with objective value $15$.

---

For $5$ players with scores $\{4,3,2,1,0\}$ and $7$ rounds, there are $7713$ multisets of possible scores to cover, and an optimal solution is $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=x_6=x_8=2, x_{10}=x_{12}=1$, with objective value $14$.

Comment: Great! A have minor comment, and two further clarifications. 
Comment: There are 16 possible end results after round 2 (you miscounted them as 14)
Q1: How did you solve the equations? By hand? I am NOT asking you to provide the intermediate steps, but do you know of a program that might do it for me? I do not understand the equations and maybe go through the solution it might help?
Q2: I see no way of altering your equations to support 5 concurrent players (same pattern of scoring as before).  I tested some numbers and it seems to be true.  Is that right?

Comment: I used the MILP solver in SAS, and I added results for $5$ players to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, You alternative optimal solution for 4 players appears to indicate 10 only chits, while you mention "objective value 11".  I guess you are missing another chit...? They do not add up to the required sum of 42. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, corrected now.